# How install conky-manager on Freya?

Tags: conky

Is it possible to install `conky-manager` on Freya? Is is compatible with Pantheon Files?

If yes how can I start Conky when my computer boots?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Open your terminal, and add a new PPA to your repositories, then install it.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install conky-manager
```

To run conky at startup, you go to Applications -> System Settings -> Applications -> Startup -> Click the + icon at the bottom left corner, enter `conky` in the the bottom text input and hit enter.

I use conky with elementary OS 0.3 Freya with no issues.

Comment: better: use `add-apt-repository` in first place to add a new PPA, that is hosted at launchpad